# SQLAlchemy transaction in FastAPI middleware: commit() not writing to db

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I understand `scoped_session` might exist for this purpose, but I wanted to attempt another way for session management. In short I want to avoid using dependency injection to each route, and simply create functions that can call a session, via SessionLocal singleton, thus accessing the same session. What I noticed is that locally, this works fine. But thats with one process running (Uvicorn running Fastapi in Docker). It seems like on my linux server with mutliple Gunicorn workers running, the implicit call to `.commit()`(exiting ctx maanger) does not seem to write changes to the database. No errors are thrown but changes are not perisisted to the database. Thanks in advance for your help

```
MiddlewareSession = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

@app.middleware("http")
async def create_db_singleton(request: Request, call_next):
    with MiddlewareSession() as session:
        with session.begin():
            SessionLocal(session) # Singleton to be used
            response = await call_next(request)
    session.close() # <- added to attempt force close connections
    return response
```

Comment: How are you accessing the session in your controller?

Comment: Using the singleton, `session = SessionLocal()`

Comment: So you're creating a new SessionLocal instance inside your controller? So you're not using the session you've created but not assigned anywhere in your Middleware? Also, I strongly recommend using the dependency system to sentralize this behaviour instead of hiding it in a middleware where it's unclear where anything comes from. A way to do this is to instead create an instance of your service class and use `Depends` with that in your controller's signature instead of working with databases directly at all.

Comment: No SessionLocal is a singleton. In the beginning of the request its intialized with a session, and any other time this session is returned. Dependency system requires passing down the db instance from route to lower level functions which I want to avoid. This works locally with one uvicorn worker, but fails in production with multiple gunicorn workers